# Why does as.character drop decimal point?

Tags: r

I'm interested to know why `as.character(5.0)` returns `5` but `as.character(5.1)` returns `5.1` in R. I tried to get an answer by reading the documentation but had no luck.

Comment: R cannot distinguish between 5 and 5.0.  Interally they are stored as exactly the same number so there is no reason to think that 5.0 would give anything different than 5.

Comment: Run `identical(5.0, 5)` to see that `5` and `5.0` are identical objects. Both are stored as doubles.

Comment: This is closely related to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal. That is, floating-point operations in any language (not just R) can produce seemingly counter-intuitive results when it comes to issues like equality, set membership, and presentation on R's console (where what you see is an approximation of what is actually in the object).

Answer (score 1):

For more precise formatting of numbers as characters, you might use `format`:

```
> format(5,nsmall = 1)
[1] "5.0"
```

Comment: No offence, but how does this answer the question? The OP asked **why** this happens

Answer (score 1):

> I'm interested to know why as.character(5.0) returns 5

The key word here is **"returns**." What do you mean by that? Note that typing this in the console gives you 5:

```
> 5.0
[1] 5
```

5 is the same things as 5.0 for the purposes of calculation. So what you probably really care about is how 5 is **printed**. You thus need to use joran's method or a function like `sprintf`.